# Jquery Append remove the escaped quote

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a Javascript with Jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/P5gD7/3/

```
var libelle = 'tes\'te';
var id = 1;
var toAdd = "<input type='text' name='choix[" + id + "]' value='" + libelle + "' />";
$("#test").append(toAdd);
```

The problem is when I've a quote in "libelle" variable (i've escaped this quote), when I use append, Jquery put only tes in the "value" attribute.
I have to do with simple quote.
For info an alert(toAdd) return me the entire input with no errors.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Because your delimiter is a `'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use jQuery to create the element for you through properties instead of string manipulation you can avoid these kind of problems:

```
var libelle = 'tes\'te';
var id = 1;
$('<input />', {
    type: 'text',
    name: 'choix[' + id + ']',
    value: libelle
}).appendTo('#test');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/P5gD7/4/)

Comment: What about the additionnal text ? for exemple if I want display this html : Test Variable : <input ....
The appendTo function put my input directly into the div I can't add text before the input.

Comment: @Warks, thats true, however you can use `before()` or `after()` to insert text into the DOM around the `input` as required.

Answer (score 1):

One approach here is to create the element, then set the value on that element. These can be chained together something like:

```
var libelle = "tes'te";
var id = 1;
var toAdd = "<input type='text' name='choix[" + id + "]' />";

// create the element, show and finally set the value (.val)
$(toAdd).appendTo("#test").val(libelle);
```

[**See The Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/P5gD7/5/)